Ocean Controller: does k8s namespace matter?
I am looking into installing Ocean Controller Version 2 with the helm command:
helm upgrade --install --wait spot-ocean-metric-exporter spot/ocean-metric-exporter \
--namespace "spot-system" \
--set oceanController.namespace="spot-system" \
--set oceanController.configMapName=ocean-controller-ocean-kubernetes-controller \
--set oceanController.secretName=ocean-controller-ocean-kubernetes-controller

Here, it looks like the recommended kubernetes namespace spot-system.  Is there any flexibility in using a different kubernetes namespace?  Eg, could I use kube-system, and in that case, would the Ocean Controller still be able to retrieve the relevant resource events from k8s that it requires?

Namespaces are just placeholders for resources...
Some operators watch all namespaces (and need a ClusterRoleBinding). Some just watch the local one (and use a RoleBinding)
So, the answer will depend on what else gets installed in your cluster.
IMO, you should not add non-k8s operators into kube-system.
